# Opensmtpd can relay mail from a list to any domain?

Tags: email, smtp, opensmtpd

[My company briefly like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH7jy.png)

I have 1500 IP addresses SMTP source and Exchange 2016 (Behind KEMP LB)
Due to LB topology, my anonymous SMTP relay receive connector scopes store on Exchange server. Now I can control anon. SMTP relay traffic by using DNS (stmp.company.com) But, due to availability concerns and redundancy I want to move this IP address to OpentSMTPd server.
My idea, all SMTP mail sources send mails to opensmptd server  and opensmtpd server relays those mail to Exchange 2016 server.

When I try to configure smtpd.conf file;

- I can create rule for from any domain to specific domain:

> ```
> accept from any for domain "syt314.yasarsap.grp" relay via smtp://smtp.company.com:25
> ```

- But I can1t create rule about **from a table to any domain** by using "relay via"

> table sourceaddr  file:/etc/opensmtpd/sourceaddr
>
> accept from source <sourceaddr> for domain any relay via
> smtp://smtp.company.com:25

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Sending mail is a difficult business, you need proper DNS PTR records to do things right, why not use services created for this?

Comment: I have Load balancer and exchange-LB couple is not work preperly in my opinion. I have to move all 1500 address to LB access list. But i causes CPU problem on LB.

Comment: Additionally, smtp://exchangeserver.company.grp:25 my inner domain server

Comment: please update this ugly question with more context and how big is your client base in case of 1.5k servers?

Answer (score 0):

> accept from source <sourceaddr>  for  any relay via

solves my problem I think